# How to use stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:

Tags: ios, json, encoding, utf-8, nsstringencoding

I've tried to load a file with unknown encoding. This is because I dont always have control over the file that I will load. I assumed that the method `stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:` will do this and will let me know the file encoding. Unfortunately following code doesn't provide the encoding I want - it always return `0`.

```
NSStringEncoding *encoding = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                       usedEncoding:encoding
                                              error:&error];
NSLog(@"\n%lu\n%@",(unsigned long)encoding,error);
```

It returns content of file, so you may wonder why I need this encoding, well that string is JSON that I want to serialize it into NSDictionary and the `dataUsingEncoding:` method requires encoding. I tried to pass `encoding` variable but this throws an error. So I tried fail safe UTF8 encoding and then it worked.

```
    NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

So I must using this incorrect as `encoding` equals to `0` instead of `4` (UTF8). Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that :

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *json = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                   usedEncoding:&encoding
                                          error:&error];
NSLog(@"\n%lu\n%@",(unsigned long)encoding,error);
```

To be clearer, you can't receive the encoding value in your pointer, you need to give a plain `NSStringEncoding` address

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not aware of the encoding of the file, I will suggest you to see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/readingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003459-SW4).
Its basically String Programming Guide which will let you know in depth what to do.

Below is the snapshot for which you are looking into:

[image]

Hope this will help you. Happy coding :)